# API resolved without sending a response in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, next.js

I have to make some changes in my NextJS project because my endpoint API doesn't support many calls and I would like to make a refresh from the original data every 3 min.

I implemented API from NextJS: I created a `pages/api/data` and inside, I make the call to my endpoint, and in my `getInitialProps` inside index call to data file.

The get works okay, but I have 2 problems:

**1:** I have an alert message that says:

> API resolved without sending a response for /api/data, this may result in stalled requests.

**2:** It doesn't reload data after 3 minutes... I suppose it is because of the Cache-Control value.

This is my code:

**pages/api/data**

```
import { getData } from "../../helper";

export default async function(req, res) {
  getData()
    .then(response => {
      res.statusCode = 200
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=180000');
      res.end(JSON.stringify(response))
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.json(error);
      next();
    });
};
```

**pages/index**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Index = props => {

  return (
    <>Hello World</>
  );
};

 Index.getInitialProps = async ({ res }) => {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/data')
  const users = await response.json()
  return { users }
};

export default Index;
```

Comment: have you tried to await getData()?

Comment: Hi Alessio, I try whit the await and the alert message disappear! but the data returns 4 time now...

Comment: You need to add a `return` statement before `getData()`, e.g. `return getData().then(...).catch(...)`

Answer (score 44):

[You should return a Promise and resolve/reject it.](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/10439#issuecomment-583214126)

Example:

```
import { getData } from "../../helper";

export default async function(req, res) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getData()
      .then(response => {
        res.statusCode = 200
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=180000');
        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.json(error);
        res.status(405).end();
        resolve(); // in case something goes wrong in the catch block (as vijay commented)
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: Code snipped in the answer might throw UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning if there is an error. In the catch block you should do: res.status(405).end(); return resolve()

Comment: Returning a promise from an async function is redundant.  Better to use `await` on `getData`, ditch all the nesting, and return whatever values you please rather than `resolve`ing.

Comment: I totally aggree that returning an explicit `Promise` is not always necessary in in an `async` function. But in my opinion there is nothing useful to return if we're using `await`. The thing here is that NextJS only wants some return value from that function it doesn't matter what it is. Returning something like `data.someValue` might be confusing here.

Comment: I had the same error.
I forgott to add `await` in front of an async function inside my api default function.

Answer (score 14):

For me it was necessary to `return` the result, even though the result was given to the client without `return`:

**Before:**
`res.status(405).json({ message: 'Method not allowed.' });`

**After, error resolved:**
`return res.status(405).send('Method not allowed.');`

[EDIT]: corrected to use `send` instead of `json` for error return value.

Comment: Not sure about this, `.json` returns void, and isn't async, so it wouldn't be much different from a plain return anyway would it?

Comment: changed `.send({message: 'not found'})` to `.send('not found')` for it to work

Answer (score 13):

```
import { getData } from "../../helper";

export default async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const response = await getData();
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=180000');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
  }

  catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
    res.status(405).end();
  }
}
```

Comment: .end() fixed it - thanks

Comment: Why is it better to use the async flow instead of `.then().catch()`? Don't they behave the same effectively?

Answer (score 5):

You can try adding the following additional export to your "pages/api/xxxx" API page:

```js
// pages/api/xxxx

export const config = {
  api: {
    externalResolver: true,
  },
};
```

You can find more details about following config here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/request-helpers#custom-config

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for. I am using express on the API routes with nextjs and awaiting a promise was resolving the request too soon.

Comment: Is there a solution to implement this kind of config for every api in one place?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to fix the error since you are using async and fetching data, just add await before fetch :

```js
import { getData } from "../../helper";

export default async function(req, res) {
  await getData()
    .then(response => {
      res.statusCode = 200
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=180000');
      res.end(JSON.stringify(response))
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.json(error);
      next();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only get this error after using `next export` but it works fine with `next dev` or `next start` then you probably have a CORS issue.

In the browser network tab, is there an OPTIONS call paired with your GET (or whatever)?  If so, you need to handle the OPTIONS call and set the CORS headers:

```js
export default async (request: NextApiRequest, response: NextApiResponse<IStudy[]>) => {
  response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  if (request.method == 'OPTIONS') return response.status(200).end();
  // rest of your function starts here...
```

Obviously don't be so free with your headers in a production environment...

You can set these headers everywhere at once in nextjs.config.js like so:

```
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  headers: () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/(.*)',
        headers: [
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: '*' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', value: '*' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', value: '*' },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
```

But in each api route you'll still need to prepend the line

```js
if (request.method == 'OPTIONS') return response.status(200).end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'next-connect' library which eliminates the necessity of returning a promise in this scenario. If you like `express.js`'s `route->middleware->endpoint` pattern this library is what you are looking for. It also provides global error handling out of the box! [[next-connect docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-connect)]

Example:

```
import nc from 'next-connect'

function onError(err, req, res, next) {
  logger.log(err);

  res.status(500).end(err.toString());
  // OR: you may want to continue
  next();
}

const handler = nc({ onError });

handler
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.user){
      throw new Error("oh no!");
      // or use next
      next(Error("oh no"));
    }
  })
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.end("success")
  })
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. The warning still persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    switch (req.method) {
      case "GET": {
        try {
          let response = await fetch(
            "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
          );
          res.status(200).send(await response.json());
          return resolve();
        } catch (error) {
          res.status(500).end();
          return resolve();
        }
      }
    }
    res.status(405).end();
    return resolve();
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to the code sample, but I also got this error using the next APIs.

The issue was a wrong HTTP method that wasn't being accounted for in the handler.

I was calling a get, and the handler was expecting a post.

So just check out for this also.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It's also good to mention that the res.send() method is a way to send the response and automatically call res.end() under the hood.