# Next.js API Routes response empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, next.js

I have try some method to fetch database using mysql. Here what i try:

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
    const mysql = require('mysql')
    const dbConn = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '*******',
        user: '*******',
        password: '*******',
        database: '*******'
    })
    dbConn.connect((err) => {
        if (err) throw err
    })
    var data
    dbConn.query(`SELECT * FROM training`, (err, result, fields) => {
        data = JSON.stringify(result)
    })
    res.end(data)
}
```

I got nothing:
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOniG.png)

Please I don't know how to fetch database directly with next.js

Comment: put the res.end(data) inside the callback, after the line data=JSON.stringify(result);, in case of err, send the err

Comment: But I got a message from the console, says "API resolved without sending a response for /api/users, this may result in stalled requests." is this okay?

Comment: you can make the handler async and use Promise to wrap the dbConn.query as specified here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684227/api-resolved-without-sending-a-response-in-nextjs, it should solve the warning

Answer (score 0):

You are sending/ending the response before the database query has resolved. Instead move the end/send to inside the callback:

```
dbConn.query(`SELECT * FROM training`, (err, result, fields) => {
     res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
     // res.status(200).json(result)
})
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: But I got a message from the console, says **"API resolved without sending a response for /api/users, this may result in stalled requests."** is this okay?

Comment: @Redcursed Instead of `res.end(JSON.stringify(result));` can you instead try `res.status(200).json(result);` inside the callback. That being said, can you also confirm that `err` is falsy/null/undefined inside the query callback.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with Scope.

You will need to hand `data` into your Query function, or you can call `res.end(data)` inside your .Query function.

Handing in data might look like something like this: (without looking at the Docs)

```
dbConn.query(`SELECT * FROM training`, (err, result, fields, data) => {
        data = JSON.stringify(result)
    })
```

Calling res.end() inside your .Query function

```
dbConn.query(`SELECT * FROM training`, (err, result, fields) => {
     res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
})
```