# API resolved without sending a response when trying to fetch data from separate page

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have an endpoint setup that queries an external database and page that calls that endpoint
inside of `getServerSideProps`. With the following code,
When I visit the API endpoint the data is successfully returned but when I go to the page I I get this error: `API resolved without sending a response for /api/get_bans, this may result in stalled requests.`

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  let bans = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/get_bans').then((res) => { 
    return res.json();
  })

  return {
    props: { bans: bans }
  }

}
```

API Endpoint

```
import db from '../../db.js';

const handler = (req, res) => {
  if(req.method == 'GET') {
    db.connect();
    db.query('SELECT * FROM tf2jr_guardbans_logs', (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.status(200).json(results);
    })
  }
}

export default handler;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [API resolved without sending a response in Nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684227/api-resolved-without-sending-a-response-in-nextjs)

Comment: If you're having a problem with the request handler for `/api/get_bans`, then please show us all the code for that request handler.

Comment: Also, `if (error) throw error;` should NEVER be inside a plain asynchronous callback.  Log the error and send an actual error response such as `console.log(err); res.sendStatus(500)` when you get that error. Throwing there will do you no good at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 what are you even saying in your last comment? It waits for the fetch to finish, then in the callback function it returns the response then `getServerSideProps` returns that

Comment: @JordanBaron - OK, I was confused by `res.json()` which is the same syntax that is used when sending a JSON response to an http request.  I thought you were sending an http response.  So, that comment will be deleted.

Comment: Also, what happens when `handler()` is called, but the method is not GET.

Comment: @jfriend00 nothing will happen, but fetch is always a GET, no? Also, I found the problem to be that in the Node MySQL package docs, it says to use `connection.connect()` and `connection.close()` and apparently they're un needed, so I'll update my question and answer it myself. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

if you replace

`if (error) throw error;`

with

`if (error) return res.status(500).json(error.message);`

you should see the actual error