API resolved without sending a response for /api/create-checkout-session, this may result in stalled requests
// .../api/create-checkout-sessionStorage.js

import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

export default async function handler(req, res)
 {
  const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

  const stripe = await stripePromise;

  // Your Stripe code using the `stripe` object goes here...

  const { items, email } = req.body;

  console.log(items);

  console.log(email);
}

what will be the solution for getting off this error

Hi I came to remove the stripe-payments tag as this seems to be more about Next, but was unable to do so due to the low amount of context in your question. You may want to revise it to provide more details. Similar questions also seem to exist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684227/api-resolved-without-sending-a-response-in-nextjs.  Offhand it doesn't look like your endpoint is sending a response to the requests it receives, does the error subside if you begin sending a response?
